# How to initialize NSArrays / NSMutableArrays when declared as properties

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I need some help in understanding how to use NSArrays / NSMutableArrays as properties.

1. What property attributes should the arrays be : strong or copy ? In which case should I use which attribute?
2. How do I initialize the arrays in code.
3. Should my property array be NSArray or NSMutableArray

Currently the way I am doing it 2 different ways as below. But it is all patchy and done with no clear understanding of the mechanics of it. Which one of it is correct or incorrect.

Approach 1

---

```
 .m file
    interface() 
           @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfData;
    implementation
         <....other code>

          self.arrayOfData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
         [self.arrayOfData addObject:<my object>]
```

Approach 2

---

```
 .h file
         @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayOfData;
 .m file
     //Property setter
        - (void)setListOfData:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
              if (_arrayOfData != newList) {
                    _arrayOfData = [newList copy];
              }
          }     

     //Function which initializes the arrayOfData

       NSMutableArray *newData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       .....<code which adds data>
       self.arrayOfData = newData;
```

Comment: This is overly general. I could write an entire chapter of a book about each of your questions.

Comment: You need to specify whether this is an array which is created empty and modified over time, or one that's conceptually (if not actually) read-only, is fully initialized on creation, and is never subsequently modified.

Comment: The array is being modified. I am adding data to array using addObject. My confusion is how to actually initialize it , using approach 1 or approach 2 when I use it in the code i.e. outside the setter / getter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## NSArray or NSMutableArray

Well, whether to use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` depends heavily on your use case.
Are you changing the contents of the array during runtime but only few items here or there? Use `NSMutableArray` (perfect for editable `UITableView`s data sources). Do you always reload the data source with completely new data? I'd just use `NSArray` in that case.

## strong or copy

That again depends on what you want to do. If, when someone calls the property you want them to get their own copy of the data source, use `copy`. But I have actually never used it this way and I think for 90 % of the use cases you will be better off using `strong`. That means that the caller of `.arrayOfData` gets a pointer to the `NSArray` in your class (and can thus detect changes to it).

## how to use

As I mentioned, I usually use `NSMutableArray` for like a `UITableView` data source. In the header file I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfData;
```

same as you. What I do differently is that in the `.m` file, I override the `getter` to lazily create me a `NSMutableArray`. I would thus leave the setter alone and put the following `getter` implementation.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) arrayOfData
{
    if (!_arrayOfData) {
        _arrayOfData = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return _arrayOfData;
}
```

This way, the first time you use `self.arrayOfData` in your class, it gets allocated and inited and saved into the instance variable. Then from the second time on it will just keep returning the instance variable. Hope this cleared it up a bit.

### edit

Sample usecase: You have a Twitter client with `TwTableViewController` showing the list of tweets. Let's say you will have a private method called `-(NSArray*)_getNewTweets` that will fetch the tweets from the server and return you an `NSArray` with them. To do this thing you create a `fetchNewData` method also. See the flow below.

`TwTableViewController.h`:

```
@interface TwTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) * downloadedTweets;
- (void) fetchNewData;
@end
```

`TwTableViewController.m`:

```
@implementation TwTableViewController

- (NSMutableArray *) downloadedTweets
{
    if (!_downloadedTweets) {
        _downloadedTweets = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return _downloadedTweets;
}

- (NSArray *)_getNewTweets
{
    NSArray * newTweets = ... //whatever magic to download new tweets
    return newTweets;
}

- (void) fetchNewData
{
    [self.downloadedTweets addObjectsFromArray:[self _getNewTweets]];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //animated would be prettier, but out of this scope
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchNewData];
}

//tableview stuff

@end
```

The first time you call `self.downloadedTweets`, the array will get created empty and you can just keep adding/moving/removing items. No need to overwrite this array for another one, one is enough. I used `-addObjectsFromArray:` but of course you can use `-addObject:` also. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It it clear up a little. The getter will return an empty array, now how do I add data to it. Do I add data directly to it i.e. something line [self.arrayOfData addObject:<myObject>] or do create a local nsmutable array, add data to it and then assign that local array to my property array i.e. NSMutableArray *localArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]  [localArray addObject:<id>]. Then do say  self.arrayOfData = localArray;  or self.arrayOfData = [localArray copy]

Comment: Let me expand my answer to answer that.

Comment: Also, the `copy` method does only a shallow copy, you know that? So if you have `NSArray * arr = @[a, b, c]` and call `NSArray * arrCopy = [arr copy]`, your `arrCopy == @[a, b, c]`, not `arrCopy != @[aCopy, bCopy, cCopy]`.

Comment: +1. Great explanation. Any way you could explain to me what `self.myArray` is doing from the scope of a method in your class' .m file?

Comment: @Chisx Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: "This way, the first time you use `self.arrayOfData` in your class, it gets allocated and inited and saved into the instance variable. Then from the second time on it will just keep returning the instance variable. Hope this cleared it up a bit."

I guess I'm just asking what does `self.arrayOfData` do in code? This kind of confused me when I read it. If you could elaborate that that'd be really cool.

Comment: Oh ok, the code for the `downloadedTweets` getter is above. It just checks whether we already have a saved instance variable with the array. If not, it creates a new one and assigns it to the instance variable. Then it returns the pointer to that array.